# How to force Event.curentTarget for dispatched events on global listeners in javascript?

Tags: javascript

### I got a question about dispatching events in Javascript.

Here is a little code section providing the **intro**, which works as expected.
The **event.currentTarget** is the same as if I directly clicked on the button itself.

```js
var button1 = document.querySelector('.button1');
button1.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    alert(`Button1 was clicked!\nEvent currentTarget: ${e.currentTarget} .${e.currentTarget.className}`);
});

var event = new Event('click');
button1.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<p>if you load the page a button click will be dispatched</p>

<button class="button1">Button1: If you click me I wil open an alert</button>

<p>Expected Output: "Button1 was clicked! [object HTMLButtonElement] .button1"</p>
```

### Question: Why is different if I have a listener on the document.

Event.currentTarget seems to be the element from where the event was dispatched from, not the element where dispatch **was called on**.

```js
var button1 = document.querySelector('.button1');
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    alert(`Button1 was clicked!\nEvent.currentTarget: ${e.currentTarget} .${e.currentTarget.className}`);
});

var event = new Event('click');
button1.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<p>Click anywhere besides the button itself to see the difference!</p>

<button class="button1">Button1: If you click me I wil open an alert</button>

<p>Expected Output: "Button1 was clicked! [object HTMLButtonElement] .button1"</p>
<p>Actual Output: "Button1 was clicked! [object HTMLHtmlElement]"</p>
```

### Is there a way to force the event.currentTarget?

Ideally I want to use a global listener handling multiple purposes and check per event.target if that button was clicked.

**So how can I differentiate between any other clicks and the dispatch event for the button while still using a global event listener**

[One slightly more detailed demo can be found on codepen!](https://codepen.io/Type-Style/pen/ExEKQxe)

Comment: So how is his question different than the other one you asked?

Comment: @epascarello
I deleted the other one, it included mistakes and wrong assumptions. I still don't know how to distinguish between any other click events I might have and the one that is dispatched.

Comment: `currentTarget` is what the event was bound too. `target` is what triggered it. Thought that was discussed in the one you deleted.

Comment: @epascarello Yes correct, but it is not really what I want. If I call button1.dispatchEvent(event); I want to let it bubble up to the document handler and still know that is was called upon the button1

Comment: Well my deleted answer on the other question showed you how to bubble it up. `new Event('click');` is not set to bubble

Comment: I was not able to read the deleted answer unfortunatly. Could you explain it to me how to achieve it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246286/discussion-between-type-style-and-epascarello).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the actual question is how to make an event triggered bubble up a tree? Use `MouseEvent` and set it to bubble.

```js
var button1 = document.querySelector('.button1');
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log( e.target.nodeName, e.currentTarget.nodeName);
});

const event = new MouseEvent("click", {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
});
button1.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<button class="button1">Click</button>
```

Comment: The normal dispatch I was using also bubbles up.